# Boost ASIO Network Timing Issue

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I am using boost::asio to implement network programming and running into timing issues. The issue is currently most with the client.

The protocol initially begins by the server returning a date time string to the user, and the client reads it. Up to that part it works fine. But What I also want is to be able to write commands to the server which then processes them. To accomplish this I use the io_service.post() function as shown below.

```
io_service.post(boost::bind()); // bounded function calls async_write() method.
```

For some reason the write tries happens before the initial client/server communication, when the socket has not been created yet. And I get bad socket descriptor error.

Now the io_service's run method is indeed called in another thread.

When I place a sleep(2) command before post method, it work fine.

Is there way to synchronize this, so that the socket is created before any posted calls are executed.

Comment: Why don't you call `async_write` from the completion handler of read, or from any function, which is called after "initial client/server communication" is done? Take a look at asio examples.

Comment: why the downvote?. My question is simple, how come the when I do the post command it gets executed before the actual socket instance is set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the socket and establishing the connection using `boost::asio`, you can define a method to be called when these operations have either completed or failed. So, you should trigger your "posted call" in the success callback.

Relevant methods and classes are :

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::async_resolve(...)
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_connect(...)
```

Comment: Another solution would be to post your bounded function and your socket-creation function on the same [strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html), that way if the socket-creation function is called first, the `strand` makes sure it will end up before the second function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the links below

will give u some help

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html